# How to use Multiple result sets in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets similiar to the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_XXXX 
(
    XXXXXX
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT XXXXXXX    


IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SELECT     XXXXXXX



RETURN
```

I want my report to use the first result set if it has data or use the second one in case the first one is empty. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sproc "union all" your two result sets.  If you need to tell them apart add a derived column indicating the original result set.

```
select 'ds1' as dataset, *
from table1
union all
select 'ds2' as dataset, *
from table2
```

Another try

Dump result set 1 into a temp table and only execute the second query if it's empty.

pseudo code:

```
select * into #tempResult 
from table 1

if table1 is empty 

select * from table2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem with using union all is that I want the select statement to be run only if the first one returns no rows.

Comment: you can dump result set 1 into a temp table and only execute the second query if it's empty.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I finally ended up creating a temporary Table variable in SP. Curious to know why reporting services OOB does not support multiple result sets. One more approach could be I can write a WebService and use XML data source and write the logic in WebService

Comment: Excellent.  Glad it works.
Not going to say SSRS can't do it haven't tried, but I would avoid it anyways.  I'll jump on any chance not to include business logic in the presentation layer.  :)