# Not getting Multiple DataSets when we call stored proc that returns multiple DataSets in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report

I have SP called "GetDUPRecords" and this SP will perform some operations and returns 3 result sets.

First Result Set: will get More records, basically need to display in SSRS Report.
Second Result Set: will give one row on doing some operations on Result set 1.
Third Result Set: will give one row on doing some operations on Result set 1.

SO When i am creating Data Set in SSRS report to use this SP it is considering only First Result set it is not creating or selecting another 2 result sets.

There is a bad solution i have i.e. create 3 individual SP's for each result set  but i think this is not optimistic because 3 sp's contains same code up to Resultset1.

Please suggest me how to use that Multiple result Sp in SSRS report.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why community wiki? And possible duplicate of [How to use Multiple result sets in Reporting Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567141/how-to-use-multiple-result-sets-in-reporting-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS does not support multiple datasets per call.

Another way, it can only process one resultset per call.

It was also [raised on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125454/reporting-services-recognize-multiple-result-sets-returned-from-a-stored-procedure)